# Transportation from Frankfurt Hahn airport to Bochum

Tags: public-transport, germany, airport-transfer, hhn

My friend and I will fly to Frankfurt Hahn airport and we need to go to Frankfurt main HBF, because we have to go to Bochum. What is the cheapest way to go from Frankurt Hahn to Frankfurt HBf and from Frankfurt Hbf to Bochum?

Comment: Hahn airport is named "Frankfurt" purely for marketing reasons, it is 100 km or so from the city. Travelling to Frankfurt in order to continue to Bochum is quite a detour. Consider taking the bus to Koblenz instead, then train from there (about 3.5 hours total, compared to about 5 hours via Frankfurt; likely cheaper, too).

Comment: Have you considered flying into Dusseldorf (DUS) instead?  There are direct  trains from DUS airport to Bochum, taking about 35 minutes and costing as little as EUR 13.50 or less.  Compare with 3.5 hours and EUR 60+ to travel from Frankfurt Hahn to Bochum (even when using the faster/cheaper route via Koblenz).  Even if the airfare to Dusseldorf is a bit more expensive, you might well come out ahead in money and time.  Cologne (CGN) might also be a reasonable compromise.

Comment: Dortmund (DTM) is litteraly next door. Weeze (NRN) is also an interesting option.

Comment: Should you have booked a saver fare train ticket ("Sparpreis") from Frankfurt HBF to Bochum already, then you can still cancel it for 17,50 Euro fee. Alternatively, you could check for the train that you booked if it stops at Koblenz anyway. In this case, you can still use the same ticket and get on the train in Koblenz instead.

Answer (score 4):

It is not necessary to travel through Frankfurt. You can take a bus from Hahn to Koblenz and catch a train there. Many northbound trains from Frankfurt to Köln and onwards go through Koblenz. And the fare from Hahn to Koblenz is a bit lower: 11.20 EUR vs. 15 EUR (or 14 EUR if you buy the tickets online).

=> [Buses to and from Hahn Airport](https://www.hahn-airport.de/default.aspx?menu=by_bus&cc=en)

The full fare for a second class [train](http://bahn.de) ticket for 2 persons from Koblenz to Bochum is 84 EUR (or 88 EUR if an ICE train is involved). It can be much cheaper if you book the tickets in advance and commit to specific trains. If you choose to travel on regional trains (RE, RB and S-Bahn), you can buy a [Quer-durchs-Land Ticket](http://www.bahn.de/p_en/view/offers/national/regional/quer-durchs-land-ticket.shtml) for 52 EUR. In that case you don't have to book in advance or commit to trains. It's fully  flexible and not much longer than a trip on an IC or ICE train.

Answer (score 3):

As has been pointed out, going through Frankfurt (Main) may not be necessary. [Busradar](https://www.busradar.com/) gives a good overview of your options for bus and rail travel (they even include blablacar).

In case you have to go to Frankfurt (Main) for some reason, your best guess is the 14€ bus, I'm not aware of any alternatives.